# How do I adjust UILabel width according to text width?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am making a todo list app. In one of the TableViewController, I have a stackview (with width 374) contains two labels: `"name"` and `"*"`. It combines as `"Name*"`. However, I  see warning in Xcode saying that "width and horizontal position are ambiguous for `"*"` " and "width is ambiguous for `"name"` ".
Also, I can see there is a red line between these two labels and there is a big gap after the label `"*"`. I think I can resolve it by adjusting the label width according to the text so that the stackview and also be smaller.

Is it possible to adjust the width of the UIlabel in Xcode. I have tried many ways but none of them is working.

Comment: "Adjust" how? What's the goal here? Why are there two labels in the first place? What is the stack view for? Describe the desired layout.

Comment: Hello, thanks for pointing out. I edited the questions a little bit. I have a tableview controller here. And in one of the cell, I uses a stackview to group two labels together: "Name" and an required field indicator "*". However, the label width of "*" would extend all the way to the right edge of the stackview, leaving a lot of empty space. Hope it is clear :/ @matt

Comment: Well, I ask again, if you want them together, why wouldn't you just have one label saying `Name *` and no stack view? Or if the goal is to have `Name` at the left end and `*` at the right end, why don't you just use two separate labels, and no stack view? It seems to me that the stack view is just messing you up.

Comment: So I was trying to design a todo app and following a github example. I think the example design is good so I tried to see if I was able to redo something similar to it. Based on my understanding, having a stackview makes labels organized nicer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I have a stackview (with width 374) contains two labels: "name" and "*"

That's your problem there. You have a stack view with a fixed width. I'll assume you use the default distribution property (i.e. `fill`). This creates ambiguity, Since this distribution value will try to give each arranged subview (i.e. each of your two labels) the width of its intrinsic content (i.e. the width of the text; what you really want). But you also set the stack view to be of fixed width (374). So, it doesn't know what label to "stretch" to fill the space (i.e. content hugging priority).

So, you're saying that you want to resize the stack view to wrap the labels. **You only have to remove that fixed width constraint (374)**.

Alternatively, to make thing simple, you can only use one label, and set the content like Matt have said.

Comment: Here is the structure: A big stackview contains: 1. stackview 2. content view 3. Field labels. I have constraint on this big stackview, but no constraint for the small stackview, which contains these two labels. This big stackview is included in another content view, which is in a cell. I am wondering if I should edit things to be simpler :/ So what you mean is I should remove one width constraint so that I can try to edit the width?

Comment: Yes, remove the width constraint. The stack view will figure out its size by then.